# autoresize textarea в Materialize

Tags: javascript, electron

В официальной документации Materialize указано, что для автоматического увеличения высоты textarea необходимо вызвать `$('#log').trigger('autoresize');`

Увы, у меня это выдаёт лишь ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).trigger is not a function`.

Как исправить?

Comment: jQuery подключён?

Comment: Вроде да, ошибку на `$('#log')` консоль не выдала, значит подключен

Comment: это читал? https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron

Comment: А что выдала консоль на `$('#log')`? И что значит "ВРОДЕ"?

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft `<textarea id="log" class="materialize-textarea" style="height: 43px;"></textarea>`

Comment: Пофиксил, использовал вместо `$('#log').trigger('autoresize');` `M.textareaAutoResize($('#log'));`

Comment: @ivan770 а должен был вернуть объект jQuery.  Как к примеру для этой страницы. '$('[name=comment]');'
output:
`n.fn.init [textarea.js-comment-text-input, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "[name=comment]"]`